# How to change the label size of an R plot

Tags: r, plot, dendrogram, hierarchical-clustering

I`m making a cluster plot from my data. I have the entire plot finished but my label text is to large to be able to properly read the plot. Anyone any idea how to make labels smaller.

I am using the package "sparcl", and my function is:

```
ColorDendrogram(fit,y=col.int, main = "Clusters from 216 samples",
                branchlength = 0.20, labels = fit$labels, xlab = NULL,
                sub = NULL, ylab = "", cex.main = NULL)
```

[image]

as you can see the branch text is to big and they fall over each other. I want the text of the leaves to be 25% smaller. I already looked at the documentation of the Sparcl package but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try using the `cex` parameter.

Comment: cex.main?? changes the size of the Main Title.

Comment: No, `cex` should alter the font sizes within the plot. If the function doesn't pass it along, try setting it in `par`, eg `par(cex=0.8)`

Comment: Thanks James i got it working par is an graphical parameter that automatically applies to the plot function thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

before calling the plot you should call `par()`.

```
par(cex=numericvalue)
ColorDendrogram(parameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving `cex.main` a value?
(The amount by which to enlarge the main title for the figure)