# Increase font size on plot with descdist()

Tags: r, font-size, fitdistrplus

is there a way to manipulate the font size on the plot produced by the command
`descdist()`
in the `fitdistrplus` library?

I want to store the plot by using:

```
dev.print(pdf, "output_file.pdf", onefile=TRUE, paper='A4r',
          width= 11, height = 8)
```

to be able to import it into my LaTex documentation. Unfortunately, the fonts are quite small and no one will be able to read it if I print it.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: looks like you will ahve to set the `par`ameters globally. See `?par`. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241798/how-to-increase-font-size-in-a-plot-in-r

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks.