# R Graph - graphical string measurement

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to graphically measure the width of a string. (see examples in the attached image. I have used Times New Roman with point size 11 and size 16)

Each character will have different width e.g. "a" vs "A" for the same font & font size. I am trying to look for solution to graphically plot text and programmatically measure the graphical length (in terms of "mm" or "inch")
I tried strwidth() function but it is not working correctly. e.g. gives me same value for "a" vs "A"

[R - Measure width of string using strwidth()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586435/r-measure-width-of-string-using-strwidth)

[image]

Comment: What code and what OS are you using, and what result do you get? I get different widths when I run (on OSX) `strwidth("a", units = "inches", family = "Times New Roman")` [0.07397461] and when I run `strwidth("A", units = "inches", family = "Times New Roman")` [0.1203613] so I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sorry I was trying strwidth("a", units = "inches", family = "Times New Roman", font=11). that font=11 is causing some issue. How can I specify font size ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to use `par()` with the `ps` argument.

```
 strwidth("This is a test.", units = "inches", family = "Arial", ps = par(ps = 11))
[1] 0.875

> strwidth("This is a test.", units = "inches", family = "Arial", ps = par(ps = 16))
[1] 1.333333

> strwidth("This is a test.", units = "inches", family = "Times New Roman", ps = par(ps = 16))
[1] 1.145833

> strwidth("This is a test.", units = "inches", family = "Times New Roman", ps = par(ps = 11))
[1] 0.8333333

> strwidth("This is a test.", units = "inches", family = "Times New Roman", ps = par(ps = 24))
[1] 1.75
```

A quick measure in a google doc, and it looks about right.