# R strwidth - "Times New Roman" font alias on Linux

Tags: r, ggplot2, extrafont

I am using strwidth() function (see link below) and looking for a solution to define font-alias for Times New Roman on Linux

[R Graph - graphical string measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587352/r-graph-graphical-string-measurement)

Could we define font-alias as described for svglite in below link

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svglite/vignettes/fonts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Linux distros use Fontconfig to define font aliases.  These should be respected by most of the graphical devices that R uses.

For example, to define Tinos as an alias for Times New Roman, you can add the following lines to the file `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`, between the `<fontconfig>` and `</fontconfig>` tags.

```
<match>
    <test name="family"><string>Times New Roman</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="strong">
      <string>Tinos</string>
    </edit>
</match>
```

Note that, if `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` does not exist already, you will need to create it and put the following lines into it first

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
</fontconfig>
```

If you want to apply these changes system wide rather than just for one user, then instead edit `etc/fonts/local.conf` instead.

Comment: thanks, this answers my question. Your response triggered whether I should be installing Microsoft Fonts on Linux. I started a new thread for that question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347140/install-microsoft-fonts-on-linux-and-use-it-in-r