# How to increase the font size of the scales in a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, size, scale, scatter-plot

I am trying to include some plots as part of my dissertation but the font size of the scales are too small. Is there a way to make it look bigger?

[Image of the plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j63P.png)

Here is my code

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = wccplots_long, aes(x = wcc.group, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_quasirandom(aes(colour = as.factor(X28_day_mortality) , shape = sex, fill = as.factor(X28_day_mortality)), width = 0.4) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1 )) +
  labs(x = "WCC Group", y = "Protein level in plasma", title = "Top 5 downregulated Proteins", fill = "Mortality", shape = "Sex", colour = "Mortality",cex.lab=3, cex.axis=3, cex.main=3, cex.sub=3 ) +  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", comparisons = list(c("Low", "Medium"), c("Low", "High"), c("Medium", "High") ), aes(label = ..p.signif..)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values =c("red", "black")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values =c("red", "black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values =c(24,22)) + facet_wrap(~Protein, ncol = 5, scales = "free_y", labeller = labeller(Protein = proteinnames)) +
   theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="skyblue1", size=2, color="black")) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"), aspect.ratio = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05,0.15) ))
```

Comment: I think this solution can help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241798/how-to-increase-font-size-in-a-plot-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241798/how-to-increase-font-size-in-a-plot-in-r)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the code that generated them? Anyway, increasing the DPI of the export can be an easy way.