# Increase Font Size of Axes: Piper Diagram

Tags: r, diagram, axes

I am using the package 'hydrogeo' https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hydrogeo/hydrogeo.pdf to create piper plot diagrams.

How can I increase font size of axes

```
rm(list=ls())
library(hydrogeo)
l <- list( Ca = c(43,10,73,26,32),
           Mg = c(30,50,3,14,12),
           Cl = c(24,10,12,30,43),
           SO4 = c(24,10,12,30,43))

lp <- piper(l)
lp@pt.pch = c(15,17,18,15,17)
lp@pt.col = c(4,1,3,5,2)
plot( lp, main="Piper-Hill Diagram of Water Quality", cex=1.2)
```

I try with a theme and cex.axis

Comment: To improve the chance of getting a good answer you should add a reproducible example, and explain what you have tried so far.  That is, what code are you using to get plots, and how does the package documentation not answer your question?

Comment: Looks like hydrogeo uses base plot, try something like: `plot(x, cex.axis = 1.2)`, meaning increase size by 20%.

Comment: Possible duplicate, related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4241798/680068